# Transition maps in trivial direct limit

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

If $\{X_i, i\in I\}$ is a directed system of abelian groups such that we have
$$\varinjlim_{i\in I}X_i = 0$$
is it true that for every $i$ and large enough $j\ge i$ the transition map $f_{i,j} : X_i\to X_j$ is the zero map?

If the transition maps satisfy this, then of course the direct limit is zero. If the $X_i$ are finitely generated abelian groups then the converse is also clearly true. The question is for general abelian groups $X_i$ (I'm happy to assume the $X_i$ are all countably generated and that $I=\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: It's not true. What's true is that every element of $X_i$ will map to zero in some $X_j$, but you may not be able to choose $j$ uniformly across all elements of $X_i$ (if $X_i$ is not finitely generated). As an explicit counterexample:  take $A$ to be the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module with basis $e_1,e_2,\ldots$, $T:A \rightarrow A$ by $T(e_1) = 0$, $T(e_i) = e_{i-1}$; then $\operatorname{colim}(A \overset{T}{\rightarrow} A \overset{T}{\rightarrow} \ldots) = 0$.

Comment: @sdr that is the same counterexample I just gave.

Comment: Yes. I actually figured this out at the same time too :) Sorry for taking your time then. Of course if one assumes the transition maps (or at least a cofinal subfamily of the transition maps) have finitely generated image, then this is also a case where it works. Otherwise I agree yours is the typical example to look at. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Take each $G_n$ free abelian with basis $e_k$ with $k\in \mathbb N$.  Here $n$ runs over the natural number.   Let the map from $G_n$ to $G_{n+1}$ kill $e_0$ and send $e_k$ to $e_{k-1}$ for $k>0$.  Then no map is zero but each element in each group eventually maps to $0$ far enough down.  So the direct limit is 0.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\varinjlim_{{n\in\mathbf N}^\star}\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z
$$

Comment: This answer might be clear for an algebraist, but is quite cryptic for the rest of the world. Who are the connecting maps? How does $n$ get into play?

Comment: @AlexM. The colimit is taken over the nonzero natural number ordered by divisibility, and the maps are multiplication-by-$n$!